# Tool/script to clone SQL Server database with reduced rights (without backup functionality)?

Tags: sql-server, clone

In short, I need a way to copy a database from one server to another without access to backup functionality, i.e. read and recreate schema and other objects with statements like `CREATE TABLE`, copy data with `INSERT`, copy constraints with `ALTER TABLE` etc...

I have a database on SQL Server in a large enterprise. There is one PROD-like DB and multiple individual developer instances that are supposed to be kept in sync with it by way of running the same migration scripts. However, this is not always done and instances tend to fall behind up to the point where auto-migrate is impossible and manual migrate takes a lot of time.

Normally, we would just restore those databases from a backup, but most rights for managing the databases are reserved for dbas, as a dev I can only read/write schema and data, but not make\restore backups, so this takes a lot of bureaucracy to do. I'm looking for a script or tool to clone PROD-like database without using backup.

P.S. We have SQL Source control from RedGate that we use for part of our migration process, I'm thinking if I could use it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Source Control isn't the right tool to refresh dev environments from production. If you can't access a backup, you could try using a combination of SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare.